# Runtime error 9 when looping through file paths and opening excel

Tags: vba, excel

My code is attempting to loop through a column and open the relevant file paths in that column. For some reason on the 2nd loop though the code falls over with an

> Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

The file paths are correct, and it does not seem to error consistently so I am struggling to identify the cause. The code errors when trying to assign the ExcelFilePath the 2nd time through the loop.

```
Function OpenExcels(sHt As String) As Object
Dim J As Integer
Dim ExcelFilePath As String
Dim PathLastRow As Integer

'Open Excels
    PathLastRow = Sheets(sHt).Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For J = 6 To PathLastRow

    ExcelFilePath = Sheets(sHt).Range("R" & J).Value 'ERROR HERE

    Module1.OpenExcelCheck ExcelFilePath

    Next J

End Function

Function OpenExcelCheck(myPath As String) As Object
Dim myFileName As String
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim SaveExt As String
Dim xRet As Boolean

    myFileName = Mid(myPath, InStrRev(myPath, "\") + 1, InStrRev(myPath, ".") - InStrRev(myPath, "\") - 1)
    FolderPath = Left(myPath, InStrRev(myPath, "\"))
    SaveExt = "." & Right(myPath, Len(myPath) - InStrRev(myPath, "."))

    xRet = IsWorkBookOpen(myFileName & SaveExt)
    If xRet Then

    Else
        Workbooks.Open (myPath)
        Sleep 5000
    End If

End Function

Function IsWorkBookOpen(Name As String) As Boolean
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xWb = Application.Workbooks.Item(Name)
    IsWorkBookOpen = (Not xWb Is Nothing)
End Function
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The reason is because you refer to the ActiveSheet implicitly. And during the second time the active sheet is the sheet you just opened in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your code like this

```
Function OpenExcels(sHt As String) As Object
Dim J As Integer
Dim ExcelFilePath As String
Dim PathLastRow As Integer
Dim ws as worksheet
set ws = ActiveSheet

'Open Excels
    PathLastRow = ws.Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For J = 6 To PathLastRow

    ExcelFilePath = ws.Range("R" & J).Value 'ERROR HERE

    Module1.OpenExcelCheck ExcelFilePath

    Next J

End Function
```

or even better pass the correct worksheet at the beginning

```
Function OpenExcels(ws as worksheet) As Object
Dim J As Integer
Dim ExcelFilePath As String
Dim PathLastRow As Integer

'Open Excels
    PathLastRow = ws.Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For J = 6 To PathLastRow

    ExcelFilePath = ws.Range("R" & J).Value 'ERROR HERE

    Module1.OpenExcelCheck ExcelFilePath

    Next J

End Function
```

Comment: this has worked perfectly, thank you for the code and the explanation!